# How to drop all views in cascade manner from a schema in HSQL database

Tags: view, schema, hsqldb, drop, hypersql

I want to drop all views available in particular schema of the HSQL database and recreate them. So how to drop all the view present in particular schema of HSQL DB?

**Tried this:**

```
DECLARE view_name VARCHAR(256);
DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_schema_name';

OPEN cur;
read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO view_name;
    SET @drop_stmt = 'DROP VIEW IF EXISTS ' || view_name;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE @drop_stmt;
END LOOP;
CLOSE cur;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HSQLD does not allow DROP statements in stored procedures. You need to write your code in Java and execute `DROP VIEW anyview IF EXISTS CASCADE` for each view. Note you need the keyword CASCADE as a view that references other views cannot be dropped without this keyword.